# How know when any app send SMS

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver

How I can khow when (and address, body etc) any application send SMS (MMS)?

I find many examples for broadcastreceiver on receive SMS, but none on sending SMS.
I can't find identfilter's action on this broadcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try one thing. Register a content observer for message log. By that when A message is sent it will enlisted in message log and your observer will catch that.. .. haven't tried it yet , so better check if possible

**UPDATE:**

you have to register the observer for "content://sms". [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683116/why-my-contentobserver-is-not-being-called-when-i-send-an-sms) and the answer might help you

also check this [example](http://gbandroid.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/MobileSpy/src/org/ddth/android/monitor/observer/AndroidSmsWatcher.java) code