# Android Content observer for stop sending sms

Tags: android

Actually I want to stop user from sending sms from mobile. So after some search I find out that there is no way of getting outgoing sms listener. So, I came up with idea that using content observer on android "content://sms", after detecting change, can I stop it from sending and also delete it. And in this way, I disable user from sending sms. Is this feasible?

Comment: Rebecca, I think its not possible, how you will get that event when somebody sending an sms?

Comment: @pratik  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683116/why-my-contentobserver-is-not-being-called-when-i-send-an-sms)

Comment: Then what is the problem with this, thanks for sharing this with me.

Comment: @pratik how to stop that sms from sending?

Comment: Its quite R & D topic and very good question this is, let me research on this and get back to you Rebecca.

Comment: Its not possible Rebecca, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/nkInhkFbSzw read this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57749/discussion-between-pratik-and-rebecca).